Mongoid: query documents that have has_one relation
I have these models
class Employee
   has_one :device
end

class Device
   belongs_to :employee
end

I want to find all employees with a device.
I tried different approaches:
Employee.where(:'device'.exists => true)
Employee.where(:'device.id'.ne => nil)
Employee.where(:'device.device_uuid'.ne => nil)
Employee.includes(:device).where("devices.id is not null")

How can I do that?

device_employees = Device.all.pluck(:employee_id); Employee.in(id: device_employees ) should work. Alternately you could use the aggregation pipeline but that seems overkill for the current requirement.

thank you @engineersmnky
your solution works. as an optimization, I'm thinking of creating a document with foreign keys (device_id, employee_id) so I can query that directly
